# Getting TypeScript in Visual Studio 2015 to auto-complete on enter and auto-complete paranthesies

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I just started using TypeScript, and was using the TypeScript Playground here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

It has decent intellisense, and autocompletes on enter, as well as auto-completes parenthesis and brackets.

However, once I decided to use it in VS 2015, I noticed that enter no longer selects the suggested dropdown, and neither parenthesis nor brackets are auto-added. When programming in C#, these features work out great.

How do I enable this behavior in Visual Studio? I would assume that if it exists on the website, it would definitely exist in a full blown IDE like VS.

Can I enable similar refactoring features to C#, like automatic variable/property renaming across the project if I change a variable name? Using `Ctrl-R Ctrl-R` to rename a variable doesn't seem to work, it only changes the line I'm on.

Edit:

- VS 2015 Update 3
- <s>Typescript for VS 2015 v 1.8.6.0</s>
- Typescript for VS 2015 v 2.0

**Edit2**: Upgraded to the `TS 2.0` VS plugin. The `Automatic Brace Completion` checkbox is no longer greyed out, yet enabling it does not seem to have an effect on brace completion.

**Edit3**: These features are in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Strange how much better Visual Studio Code is compared to Visual Studio for typescript. Does anyone know if VS2017 does a better job?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript 2.0.2 RC for Visual Studio 2015 — August 30, 2016 fixed this issue. You can download [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593).

Click Details to see list of all the versions.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the latest TypeScript VS extension installed.

Comment: Rafe, I do. I just installed a new dev environment with VS 2015 Update 3, and am using TypeScript Tools for VS 2015 1.8.6.0